# Putting git hooks into repository for Windows

Tags: windows, githooks

I have created a githook folder which contains git hooks in my git repository.
What is the best way to deliver link hooks to `.git/hooks` on windows?

Answer (score 0):

suppose your hooks are in d:\githook\hooks\

1. `git init --template=/d/githook/`
   `git clone --template=/d/githook/`
2. `git config init.templateDir /d/githook/`
3. put the hooks in ..\Git\share\git-core\templates\hooks\